# Can't write to MySQL using spark API - pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to write to a MySQL table using the spark jdbc() function inside of a partition task that is called from executing foreachPartitions(test). I am however receiving a picking error.

I am not sure if the issue is due to spark already being inside of a task and spark runs the write.jdbc() as a task itself. From my understanding this isn't allowed? I can return the list "row" from my test() function and call write.jdbc() inside main but i would rather not have to collect the data structures back to the master. code and error:

CODE:

```
def test(partition_iter):
    row = []
    row.append({'col1': 26, 'col2': 12, 'col2': 153.49353894392, 'col4': 1})
    df_row = SPARK.createDataFrame(row)
    df_row.write.jdbc(url="jdbc:mysql://rds-url/db_name", table="db_name", properties={"driver":"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver","user":"user", "password":"password"}, mode="append")

def main():
    SPARK.sparkcontext.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4]).foreachPartition(test)

main()
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 107, in dump
    return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 568, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 214, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 251, in save_function_tuple
    save((code, closure, base_globals))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 554, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 606, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 642, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 208, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 256, in save_function_tuple
    save(f_globals)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 692, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 563, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 323, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name, value))
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o47.__getnewargs__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:272)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in main
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 809, in collect
    port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2439, in _jrdd
    self._jrdd_deserializer, profiler)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2372, in _wrap_function
    pickled_command, broadcast_vars, env, includes = _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc, command)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2358, in _prepare_for_python_RDD
    pickled_command = ser.dumps(command)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 440, in dumps
    return cloudpickle.dumps(obj, 2)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 667, in dumps
    cp.dump(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 120, in dump
    raise pickle.PicklingError(msg)
pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o47.__getnewargs__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:272)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are calling the Spark context from within a task, which is not allowed.

Edit following comments:

There are two ways you can partition work that creates a number of rows to be written to the DB:

```
# use mapPartitions to get an RDD of rows

def test(partition_iter):
    rows = [{'col1': 26, 'col2': 12, 'col2': 153.49353894392, 'col4': 1} for i in partition_iter]
    return rows

def main():
    rows = SPARK.sparkcontext.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4]).mapPartitions(test)

    df = SPARK.createDataFrame(rows)
    df.write.jdbc(url="jdbc:mysql://rds-url/db_name", table="db_name", properties={"driver":"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver","user":"user", "password":"password"}, mode="append")

main()
```

Or:

```
# use pymysql in each partition instead of spark sql as per your original attempt

def test(partition_iter):
    row = []
    row.append({'col1': 26, 'col2': 12, 'col2': 153.49353894392, 'col4': 1})
    # TODO: pymysql code goes here:
    # mysqldriver = ???

def main():
    SPARK.sparkcontext.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4]).foreachPartition(test)

main()
```

Comment: This is just a simple example, i was trying to abstract away from any meaningful code in order to clearly show what i wanted to do. In reality i would have a sparkSQL query inside of main() and call foreachPartitions(test) on that and do work inside of test() based on the specific partition of rows. I would then write out the result to MySQL. I would like to write out the result to MySQL while still inside of test() so that i don't have to have the master collect the result.

Like i thought this isn't possible so my choices are to either us pymysql or collect() and write out in main()

Comment: If you are forced to write from `foreachPartition`, then you must use pymysql instance in each partition. Having said that, the example code I have posted doesn't do a `collect`...

Comment: Oh, hang on, I see what you mean now:- you are partitioning work that builds a load of rows, which you need to write to mysql. Let me update my answer....

Comment: edited answer to reflect my better understanding of your problem

Comment: i noticed you mentioned that the example code you posted doesn't do a collect(). For example 1, does that mean writing out to MySQL is done where the data is stored(worker nodes) without first having the master collect it?

Comment: Yes, unless I am mistaken.